# Can std::this_thread::yield being just a hint be problematic?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, stdatomic

colleague and me discussed a hypothetical problem when one would want to implement spinlock mutex with `std::atomic_flag` , but also implement that spinlock as not while(true) but as a

```
while(true)
{
     cnt=0;
     while (cnt<yieldAfterTries)
     {
        //try to get lock
        cnt++;
     }
     std::this_thread::yield();

     // if got lock do work and then break;
}
```

Basically idea is that the thread cant block others "for a very long time" even if it has a  real time priority because it will yield after a while... but when I saw 
specification of std::yield I was surprised it is a suggestion, not a mandatory thing.

> Provides a hint to the implementation to reschedule the execution of
>   threads, allowing other threads to run.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield

So can that be problematic?

Comment: No. If your program relies on `sched_yield` or `this_thread::yield` or similar for correctness then it's already broken.

Comment: @JonathanWakely well then question is can the high priority thread that tries to spinlock block indefinately block other low prio threads(one of them holding the lock)... I guess that is a q about a scheduler. :)

Comment: Yes, it's about the scheduler, and C++ can't specify that, so it can't realistically require anything stronger from `yield()` than it being a hint.

Answer (score 6):

I've written code very similar to yours, and measured the impact of the call to `yield` under high contention conditions.  I've found the use of `yield` in this way beneficial to overall system throughput.

The actual specification is not different in spirit from what you quote, but here is the exact spec from 30.3.2 [thread.thread.this], paragraphs 2 and 3:

```
void this_thread::yield() noexcept;
```

> *Effects:* Offers the implementation the opportunity to reschedule.
>
> *Synchronization:* None.

If the implementation implements `yield` as a no-op (for example), this will impact only the performance of your code and not the correctness.  A failing spin-lock will eventually get pre-empted even without the `yield`.  But it will also be more likely to needlessly hog cpu, degrading overall system performance.

Comment: hi, nice answer, btw regarding your implementation (if you ever want to make it serious procution code) I remember watching some MIT lectures long long time ago and they mention that there is a formula for how long you should spinlock if your context switch takes time X. Unfortunately IDK exactly what video clip is that but if you are interested you can try to google it or ask ppl who might know about that.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl:  Thanks for the tip.  In fact I've made it serious production code (http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/memory.cpp search for "__sp_mut::lock()").  In this application the spin lock isn't general purpose.  It is doing something very specific.  The optimum spin count was determined empirically with timers and tests.  The minimum of the cost curve was a relatively gentle "bucket".  I.e. just getting close to the minimum was good enough.

Comment: if you ever get bored: https://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECD2AE32F507F10481 :D It gets kind of boring when they get into cilk, but general stuff is cool.

Comment: For posterity, Howard Hinnant was the lead designer and author of the <mutex>, <condition_variable> and <thread> multithreading utilities for c++11. It is safe to say that he has written some "serious production code."

Answer (score 1):

A spinlock will be automatically pre-empted by the OS scheduler making this code unnecessary. The OS will automatically switch to another thread when one thread has taken its share of time. This is why yield is a hint. In the Completely Fair Schedular in Linux, for example, the  call to yield would often cause needless context switches due to the schedular trying to correct for a thread not getting it's fair share of time.

Your attempt to get a spinlock will not block anything, only holding the spinlock will cause other things to block.